# Google AppScript's Sheet.getName() returns object instead of string

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to find a specific sheet in my SS by characters contained in it.

I have the following function:

```
function findSheetResponse()
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var allsheets = ss.getSheets();
  for(i in allsheets)
  {
    var responsesheet = new String;
    responsesheet = allsheets[i].getName();
    if(responsesheet.indexof("Form Responses")>-1)
    {
      Logger.log(responsesheet);
    }
    else
    {
    }       
  }    
}
```

This is the error given by the execution

```
TypeError: Cannot find function indexof in object Form Responses 10. (line 19, file "Code")
```

In don't get it. [getName()In the docs,  is supposed to return a String](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/named-range#getName()), so I should be able to use it as a String, not an object...

Any idea ?

Comment: The answer below is correct but remember that a JavaScript string is also an object... so does about everything in JavaScript.

Comment: indeed. the "object Form Responses 10" got me confused...

Comment: I came here because getName() (of a file) does not return a String either. I wanted to use file.getName().includes("x"), but I get an error that includes does not exist for object that is the result of file.getName(). Using `var filename = String(file.getName());` and then `filename.includes("x")` also doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `indexOf()` the 'O' is in lower case.[(doc)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)